# acumatica recover a report created using advanced report designer

Tags: acumatica

I had report deployed to Acumatica created from advanced report designer. Now the report doesn't run giving an error when you click on the link (site map location created). Problem is I cannot see any option to edit the report since this error comes up very first time you click on the report link.  Some reports where you see the error after entering parameters, you can use edit button to access the report.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had errors like this as well. They have occurred where the relationship was not set up correctly in the report. To resolve, I've used views in the database to have a look at the tables concerned and determine how the relationship should look in the report. I have no idea if this is an accepted practice or not, but it worked for me.

Comment: I think you can use views in reports directly, you have to publish a view through customisation